# How to import data from csv to elasticsearch in java without using logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to import data from a csv file to elasticsearch. But I don't want to use logstatsh. So, what are the ways I can do this ? 
Any blogs ? Docs ?
I came across TransportClient, but I'm not getting the point from where to start .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.elastic.co/blog/indexing-csv-elasticsearch-ingest-node

Answer (score 0):

very late answer, however :) ….This is for elasticsearch 7.6.0

```
//this class for keeping csv each row values
public class Document {
    private String id;
    private String documentName;
    private String name;
    private String title;
    private String dob;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getDocumentName() {
        return documentName;
    }
    public void setDocumentName(String documentName) {
        this.documentName = documentName;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name1;
    }
    public void setName(String name1) {
        this.name1 = name1;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }
    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }   
}




public void bulkInsert() {
        long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        logger.debug("ElasticSearchServiceImpl => bulkInsert Service Started");
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";
        BulkRequest request;
        Document document;
        //elastic Search Index Name
        String esIndex = "post";
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(<path to CSV>));
            request = new BulkRequest();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use comma as separator
                String[] row = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                if(row.length >= 1) {
                    //filling Document object using csv columns array
                    document = getDocEntity(row);   
                    //adding each filled obect into BulkRequest 
                    request.add(getIndexRequest(document, esIndex));
                } else {
                    logger.info("ElasticSearchServiceImpl => bulkInsert : null row ="+row.toString());
                }
            }
            br.close();
            if(request.numberOfActions()>0) {
                BulkResponse bulkResponse = client.bulk(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
                if(bulkResponse.hasFailures()) {
                    logger.error("ElasticSearchServiceImpl => bulkInsert : Some of the record has failed.Please reinitiate the process");
                } else {
                    logger.info("ElasticSearchServiceImpl => bulkInsert : Success");
                }
            } else {
                logger.info("ElasticSearchServiceImpl => bulkInsert : No request for BulkInsert ="+request.numberOfActions());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("ElasticSearchServiceImpl => bulkInsert : Exception =" + e.getMessage());
        }
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        logger.info("ElasticSearchServiceImpl => bulkInsert End" + Util.DB_AVG_RESP_LOG + "" + (endTime - starttime));
    }


public static Document getDocEntity(String[] row)throws Exception {
        Document document = new Document();
        document.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        for(int i=0;i<row.length;i++) {
            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                document.setDocumentName(row[i]);
                break;
            case 1:
                document.setName(row[i]);
                break;
            case 7:
                document.setTitle(row[i]);
                break;
            case 8:
                document.setDob(row[i]);
                break;
        }

        return document;
    }


        public static IndexRequest getIndexRequest(Document document,String index)throws Exception {
            IndexRequest indexRequest = null;

Map<String, Object> jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
        jsonMap.put("doc_name",document.getDocumentName());
        jsonMap.put("title",document.getTitle());
        jsonMap.put("dob",document.getDob());

        indexRequest = new IndexRequest(index).id(document.getId()).source(jsonMap);
        return indexRequest;
        }
```

If you need to show each response, you can use the following code for responses

```
for (BulkItemResponse bulkItemResponse : bulkResponse) { 
    DocWriteResponse itemResponse = bulkItemResponse.getResponse(); 

    switch (bulkItemResponse.getOpType()) {
    case INDEX:    
    case CREATE:
        IndexResponse indexResponse = (IndexResponse) itemResponse;
        break;
    }
}
```

For more information please read official [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-bulk.html)